# While loop printing error messaged based on number of characters inputted

Tags: c, error-handling, while-loop, scanf

I'm trying to take user input (hour) and validate it as follows:

- Has to be a digit between 1 and 12

I need to check for non-numeric input and alert the user.

I have the following code:

```
char hour;

scanf("%c", &hour);

while ( !(isdigit(hour)) || (hour < 1 && hour > 12)) {
    printf("Invalid. Try again: ");
    scanf("%c", &hour);
}
```

When this loop runs, and I input more than one non-numeric character, I get the following:

```
Enter the hour: rewe
Invalid. Try again: Invalid. Try again: Invalid. Try again: Invalid. Try again: Invalid. Try again:
```

After the last "Invalid. Try again:" I can input something again as per my code.

I just have no idea what's going on however and why it prints out the error message so many times (number of characters entered + 1). I also don't think the range checking is working at all. I've tried many many variations of this (including do-while loops) to try and make it work but I've hit a wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scanf` calls are set up to only accept one character at a time.  So after you hit Enter, one character is read and the rest are still in the input buffer, waiting to be picked up by the next `scanf` call.  That's why the loop behaves as it does.

Your while loop will also never complete.  `isdigit` returns true if the character entered is '0', '1', ... '9'.  Note that these are characters, not numbers as you're thinking of them.  If you try to do arithmetic operations on them, it will be on the ASCII values of those characters.  For example, '1' has an ASCII value of 49.  So if you enter '1', the first part of the while expression will be false but the second part will be true and it will say it's invalid.

Even if you corrected the above issue, you're looking for the user to enter a value from 1 to 12, so looking at one character at a time is not the proper approach.  You should expect the user to enter a string instead.  You can do that with the `%d` modifier to `scanf` as follows.

```
int hour;
printf("Enter the hour: ");
scanf("%d", &hour);    
while ( hour < 1 || hour > 12) {
    printf("Invalid. Try again: ");
    scanf("%d", &hour);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, really helped me out!